# Resharper Refactor pattern for TryGetValue in Dictionary

Tags: c#, resharper, automated-refactoring, rider, trygetvalue

The most cumbersome piece of syntax I need to continually write is lazily initializing a container in a dictionary like:

```
ContainerRecord value;
if(!_dictionary.TryGetValue(key,out value))
{
   value = new ContainerRecord();
   _dictionary[key] = value;
}
//Container is always initialized here
```

Which I feel would be a trivial refactor pattern from:
 (At least for the explicit variable declaration and if statement part)

```
var value = _dictionary[key];
```

I know there is some new syntactic sugar in newer versions of C# that eliminate the need for pre-declaring out variables. Unfortunately I don't have access to these features in my environment and won't for the foreseeable future.

There does appear to be a "check for contains key" refactor, which is achieves almost the same result with the downside of doing the lookup twice.

Is this possible through some extension? I figured it is a common enough case that it would have already been solved somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Custom Pattern for this.

1. Open **ReSharper | Options...**.
2. Go to the **Code Inspection | Custom Patterns** node.
3. Click **Add pattern** button.
4. Select **Replace** on the top right of the dialog.
5. Add the following four placeholders with the **Add Placeholder** button:

   ```
   Type: Identifier Placeholder
   Name: value

   Type: Expression Placeholder
   Name: key

   Type: Type Placeholder
   Name: type

   Type: Expression Placeholder
   Name: dict
   Expression Type: System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<,>
   ```
6. Enter the following as the Search pattern in the text area on the top:

   ```
   $type$ $value$ = $dict$[$key$];
   ```
7. Enter the following as the Replace pattern in the text area on the bottom:

   ```
   $type$ $value$;
   if(!$dict$.TryGetValue($key$, out $value$))
   {
       $value$ = new $type$();
       $dict$[$key$] = $value$;
   }
   ```
8. *Optional*: Fill out the **Description** on the top. I used `Replace with TryGetValue`.
9. *Optional*: Fill out the **Description** on the bottom. I used the same.
10. *Optional*: Check the **Format after replace** checkbox.

The finished dialog should look like this:

[image: Search Pattern dialog]

11. Click on the `Save` button.
12. Back in the `Custom Patterns`, you can set the severity level for your new pattern on the right side using the dropdown. I selected **Suggestion**.
13. Exit the Options by clicking the **Save** button.

If you set up everything correctly, ReSharper should mark the matching patterns with the suggested fix:

[image: Suggestion on hovering]

[image: Suggestion in quick fix menu]

Comment: Wow thanks for the detailed answer. I am now using Rider full time instead of resharper in VS which I assumed would have the same settings but I can't find anything that matches what you described above in Rider. Do you know this is supported?

Comment: The relevant issues on the Rider bug tracker unfortunately show that this is not possible (yet) with Rider. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-11489

Comment: This is amazing, though I found it didn't work until I changed `dict` to an Identifier Placeholder rather than an Expression Placeholder. (I was aiming for something much simpler, just turning `value = dict[key];` into a `TryGetValue` call, so I didn't need the Type stuff at all.)